# Extreme unitary minimal models of conformal field theory

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Some of the best understood conformal field theories are the 2D unitary minimal models $\mathcal{M}(m+1,m)$ indexed by the integer $m\ge 2$ and with central charge
$$
c=1-\frac{6}{m(m+1)}\ .
$$
I would like to understand the extreme cases $m=2$ and $m=\infty$.

According to the article "Conformal symmetry and multicritical points in two-dimensional quantum field theory" by Zamolodchikov in Sov. J. Nucl. Phys. 1986 (the article is also reprinted in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ft_dNNdevLIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) edited by Itzykson, Saleur and Zuber), these should be scale invariant cases of $\mathcal{P}(\phi)_2$ theories as studied in the constructive quantum field theory literature (e.g., in the classics by [Glimm-Jaffe](https://books.google.com/books?id=VSjjBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) or [Simon](https://books.google.com/books?id=2W19BgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

In this correspondence, $\mathcal{M}(m+1,m)$ is obtained by perturbing the Gaussian fixed point using a polynomial $\mathcal{P}(\phi)$ which is even, of degree $2m-2$, and with $m-1$ wells. Some of these minimal models have been identified as the scaling limits of specific statistical mechanics models: $m=3$ is the Ising model,  $m=4$ is the tri-critical Ising model,
$m=5$ is the three-state Potts model.
However, almost all references I have seen say nothing about the simplest case $m=2$ which seems too degenerate to be worth mentioning.

Q1: Is $m=2$ really that trivial?

The multicritical correspondence suggests that this model is obtained by running the RG along a $\lambda\phi^2$ perturbation of the Gaussian fixed point. Equivalently, it would be a large-distance scaling limit of a massive free field with action $\frac{1}{2}\int\{(\partial\phi)^2+\lambda\phi^2$}.
If this is the case then this limit should be 2D Gaussian white noise.

Q2: 2D Gaussian white noise is conformally invariant by a [result of Hida and collaborators](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118787796). Did anyone compute the central charge and show it is zero?
Also, is there a relation between the $m=2$ minimal model and percolation (also with $c=0$) as well as black noise?

The other half of my question concerns the $m\rightarrow\infty$ limit.
Then the multicritical correspondence suggests the field looks almost $\mathbb{Z}$-valued since the number of potential wells becomes infinite.

Q3: is there a good explanation of why this should look more and more like the massless free field with $c=1$?

Comment: For the $c=0$, look at LCFT literature like http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4279

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I also just found this other article co-authored by Cardy where the $m\rightarrow\infty$ situation is considered: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321387903622